# How to stop Jquery-Steps?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm using the **jquery-steps** library. No method of stopping [methods](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Methods).

I'm ready to form this way,

```
    $("#servisKayit").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slide",
});
```

I'm doing checkups. **How can I stop the step?**

```
        $("a[href='#next']").click(function(){
        var txtMusteri = $("#txtMusteri").val().trim();
        var txtGsmNo = $("#txtGsmNo").val().trim();
        var txtSabitNo = $("#txtSabitNo").val().trim();
        var stepSayfa = $("#servisKayit").steps("getCurrentIndex");

        if(!txtMusteri){
            swal("UYARI","Lütfen Müşteri veya Bayi Bilgisi Giriniz!","info");
            $("#servisKayit").steps({ return false });
        }else if(!txtGsmNo && !txtSabitNo){
            swal("UYARI","Lütfen En Az 1 İletişim Numarası Giriniz!","info");
        }

    });
```

***Example : $("#servisKayit").steps({ return false });***

Comment: Try [`onStepChanging`](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#events) event

Comment: @AswinKumar I could not.

Comment: why? any difficulties

Comment: @AswinKumar I did not understand. The sample is too weak.